# Read messages from DLQ in Jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

I have below two jms queues configured in JBOSS 7.1.

```
<jms-queue name="APP.QUEUE1">
    <entry name="queue/APP.QUEUE1"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/APP.QUEUE1"/>
</jms-queue>

<jms-queue name="APP.QUEUE2">
    <entry name="queue/APP.QUEUE2"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/APP.QUEUE2"/>
</jms-queue>
```

while consuming the message, if some thing goes wrong then the message will go to Dead letter Queue that is configured as follows.

```
<address-setting match="jms.queue.APP#">
        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
        <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
 </address-setting>
```

so I have successfully delivered the message to DLQ.

Now I have written consumer for Dead letter queue, so that I can transfer back the message after fixing the issue.

the piece of code to consume the message is as follows.

```
QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
 Queue queue1=browser.getQueue();
 Enumeration messageEnum = browser.getEnumeration();
   while (messageEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        TextMessage message = (TextMessage) messageEnum.nextElement();
       }
```

from the text message,is there any chance of getting source queue (APP.QUEUE1 or APP.QUEUE2), so that I have  transfer back the same  text message with out  worrying much on message properties.

please let me know my approach is correct  or not,appricite  for better solution.

Comment: Found the answer for this . we have property as follows, message.getStringProperty("_HQ_ORIG_ADDRESS");   this property give originating address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for this. 
we have property as follows. 
message.getStringProperty("_HQ_ORIG_ADDRESS"); 
This property give originating address.